# Keypress simulation in React

Tags: reactjs, simulation, keypress

I'll try to describe my problem. When user refreshes the page, I need automatically simulate event, as he has pressed "enter". I tried this tutorial https://code-examples.net/en/q/91a01 and a lot of others, but it seems not working for me.

I assume that this keypress simulation has to be in ComponentDidMount() function, but maybe I am wrong?

Is it possible to do it without jQuery?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? When I hear this sort of thing I think that maybe you are coming at the solution from the wrong angle.

Comment: I'm assuming pressing enter normally triggers some handler function. Why not just call that function in componentDidMount? No need to simulate the keypress.